# Overriding properties to make them readonly - what about the setter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, polymorphism, setter

I have the following design goal in a class hierarchy:

There is a `BaseClass` defining some properties, which would usually be read/write:

```
public class Media
{
    public virtual object Content { get; set; }
    public virtual double recordingLength { get; set; }
}
```

The intention is to have some subclasses where this property now is readonly:

```
public class CompactDisk : Media
{
    public override object Content
    { 
        get { return this.getContent(); }
        set { 
               // THERE SHOULDN'T BE A SETTER 
            }
    }

    public override double recordingLength
    { 
        get { return 74; }
        set { 
               // NO SETTER EITHER HERE!
            }
    }
}
```

I'm lost here, because I don't know how should I implement my design intent.

Comment: Don't do that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @SLaks I don't want to do that indeed, and the LSP would be the main reason, but I don't know _what_ I should do instead to keep my design intent.

Comment: You haven't actually told us *what your intention* is, merely what the *desired outcome* is. Perhaps there *is a better way* to do this?

Comment: Your design intent is inherently wrong.

Comment: @Brown My design is to have this hierarchy where some objects have some property that can be changed (for example, the content off a hard-drive, or the content of a cassette tape, both subclasses of `Media`, but some types would have the same properties as readonly.

Comment: @heltonbiker If not all media content can be set, then `Media` should not have a setter for the content. Let derived classes *add* a setter if they want.

Comment: @hvd Could I override a property with only a getter, and on doing so _add_ a setter? I have the impression of trying to do this before and getting a compiler error...

Comment: @heltonbiker You should follow hvd's recommendation. The purpose of OOP and inheritance is that *casting to the parent type should not introduce any differences in operation.* I.e. where here you are trying to *suppress* a fundamental requirement that the `Media` class presents, instead you should use the `Media` class to present the **base** requirements, and child classes can add more. You may benefit from a second `Media` class `MutableMedia` or similar, that inherits `Media` and has a `setter` on those properties.

Comment: @heltonbiker Not by simply overriding the property, but you can do it by re-introducing the property (the `new` keyword), where the getter for the base class read-only property and the getter for the derived class read-write property do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, or really shouldn't, have a design where the sub types "hide" functionality of the base type. You can:

1. In your setters throw a `NotSupportedException`, or similar. This is how the `Stream` class behaves when you try to set the length of a stream that cannot be set.
2. Change your design. I don't see a way to get properties working the way you want (without resorting to "hiding", which IMHO isn't a good solution), but perhaps something like this:

   ```
   public interface IMedia
   {
       object Content { get; }
       double RecordingLength { get; }
   }

   public interface IWritableMedia : IMedia
   {
       void SetContent(object content);
       void SetRecordingLength(double length);
   }
   ```

Your CompactDisk would implement the just the `IMedia` interface, whereas a HardDrive class may choose to implement the `IWritableMedia` interface.

Comment: With C# it is not necessary to use `methods` for `setters`, instead look into the `new` keyword on properties.

Comment: [Here's how you can do it with properties.](http://pastebin.com/ChzemBMX) Technically this is hiding, but calls to the base class property are fully functional and call the derived class implementation.

Comment: I liked this approach, and would like to ask you an additional clarification: you got ridden of abstract classes altogether and used interfaces instead. _Supose_ I had some common behaviour for `Media` that I would like to have in `MediaBase`: 1) should `MediaBase` implement `IMedia`, or should each subclass implement it individually? 2) When should `MediaBase` be abstract? Sorry to bother, but I've been so confused with this...

Comment: @EBrown I think `new` on members is a terrible language feature and prefer not to use it. If you like to, that is fine.

Comment: @heltonbiker I chose interfaces because they are simpler to give an example for, but you can do the same think with classes as well.

Comment: @vcsjones In this case it is a very powerful and appropriate choice. *Especially* if you wish to prevent confusion to others by keeping the property mutation the same location as the property access.

Comment: @vcsjones I agree with the general objections to hiding, given `class Base` and `class Derived`, if `void f(Base b) { b.Foo(); }` is valid, then `void f(Derived d) { d.Foo(); }` should be valid too and do exactly the same thing. But I did avoid that problem in my suggestion.

Comment: Also, @vcsjones just like *any* language feature it can be abused (see [LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/10/01/taking-linq-to-objects-to-extremes-a-fully-linqified-raytracer.aspx)), but if done properly it is a **good tool** for programmers to be aware of.

Comment: @hvd Your linked code surely deserves to be in its own answer!

Comment: @heltonbiker Thanks, but thinking about it, I actually like Matías Fidemraizer's answer better, so I just gave that an upvote instead. :)

Comment: I think this answer really got the crux of the problem stated in the question: subtypes should extend base types, not restrict it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

One possible approach is using *interfaces*.

You can split your base concept into two interfaces:

```
public interface IWritableMedia
{
    object Content { set; }
    double recordingLength { set; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyMedia
{
    object Content { get; }
    double recordingLength { get; }
}
```

And then something like `CompactDisk` should only implement `IReadOnlyMedia`:

```
public class CompactDisk : IReadOnlyMedia
{
    public object Content { get { return ......; } }
    public double recordingLength { get { return .......; } }
}
```

If you want to implement a CD-RW (rewritable), you should implement both interfaces:

```
public class RewritableCompactDisk : IReadOnlyMedia, IWritableMedia
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public double recordingLength { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can type your variables as `IReadOnlyMedia` or `IWritableMedia`:

```
IReadOnlyMedia media = new CompactDisk();
IWritableMedia media2 = new RewritableCompactDisk();
```

Now the issue is `IWritableMedia` doesn't provide *getters* and you don't want to declare another variable of type `IReadOnlyMedia`. The solution is designing a third interface called  `IReadWriteMedia` and `RewritableCompactDisk` should implement it:

```
public interface IReadWriteMedia : IReadOnlyMedia, IWritableMedia
{
}

public class RewritableCompactDisk : IReadWriteMedia
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public double recordingLength { get; set; }
}
```

Since IReadWriteMedia implements IReadOnlyMedia and IWritableMedia, now you'll be able to type variables with IReadWriteMedia and access both getters and setters:

```
IReadWriteMedia media3 = new RewritableCompactDisk();
object content = media3.Content;
media3.Content = "hello world";
```

Comment: Very, very nice! Thanks for now!

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I think it solves the actual flaw of the code sample I posted, but your approach is one that I surely will consider using anytime this problem arises in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @heltonbiker Well, no problem, I'm not here because of the points. I enjoy addressing issues :) You're welcome